# Backup the contacts to a .VCF file doesn't work

Tags: android, backup, contacts

as i'm new to Java, i've made this code by my self and some parts learned from other sources. i want to backup all the contacts information into a .vcf file in main storage or sdcard (doesn't matter) and finally retrieve them back. but in this code you can see only the backup part:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    Cursor cursor;
    ArrayList<String> vCard ;
    String vfile;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        vfile = "Contacts" + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis()+".vcf";
        getVcardString();

    }
    private void getVcardString() {
        vCard = new ArrayList<String>();
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor!=null&&cursor.getCount()>0)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            for(int i =0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
            {

                get(cursor);
                Log.d("TAG", "Contact "+(i+1)+"VcF String is"+vCard.get(i));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("TAG", "No Contacts in Your Phone");
        }

    }

    public void get(Cursor cursor)
    {

        String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
        AssetFileDescriptor fd;
        try {
            fd = this.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");

            FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
            fis.read(buf);
            String vcardstring= new String(buf);
            vCard.add(vcardstring);

            String storage_path = Environment.getRootDirectory().toString() + File.separator + vfile;
            FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(storage_path, false);
            mFileOutputStream.write(vcardstring.toString().getBytes());

        } catch (Exception e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

the problem is the code doesn't work and doesn't get exception or any error. i searched the root directory and all folders but there were no .vcf file. my permissions are: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />`
i ran this on API 17 and 24. any idea that why it doesn't work?

Comment: To get the SD-Card path you have to use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
The Environment.getRootDirectory() returns the device root "/" - you can't write (or read) in this Directory on a non-rooted-device.

Comment: Also did you take the Write External Storage Permission?

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @kapsym Ah, i didn't know that i should use that permission too, but my priority is to save that file on the device's storage. if Environment.getRootDirectory() doesn't work, so how should i save it on the device memory? (not external memory)

Comment: If you dont want External storage, then you can use the internal storage. You dont need write permission in that case and your file will be visible only to your app. Refer here - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: @kapsym Tnx, a couple o questions:   1: is my code correct now and should work properly for internal storage?

Comment: @kapsym 2: as you said i cannot see the file neither via another app nor via file manager app, would it be visible with this: i used `FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(storage_path, false);` in my code. according to Google guide i can use `MODE_PRIVATE` and some other options instead of `False`, what do you think about using `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` for second parameter? would it make the file visible to be seen via file manager? if no, how can i make sure that my app made the file and do work properly?

Comment: If you use internal storage, there is no way for the file to be visible to a file manager. To test these kind of files, you can test on simulator where you can browse through files created in your app folder. Or you can also verify by writing a test code to read the file.

Comment: If you want it to to be seen by other apps or file manager, you have to use External Storage. Also i think MODE_WORLD_READABLE had now been deprecated so no point using it as it will crash above 4.4 devices.

Comment: @kapsym read below, my answer please.i'm using Genymotion for testing all these stuffs. it seems the app has a weird problem. now i changed the directory to DataDirectory. focus on this path (not external) i even tested this with giving permissions. but same error. look at below.

Comment: @kapsym any solution?

Comment: Sorry I didnt check yesterday as i was stuck somewhere else. I am not familiar with Genymotion but after seeing your below comments looks like your data directory is not accessible. So then none of your toasts are shown in that scenario?

Comment: @kapsym Genymotion is accessible in Android Studio and is the best tool for testing the apps on virtual devices. the toasts only are shown when i haven't entered any number to any of contacts. as soon as i enter a number to any of contacts and run the app, it crash and don't even show the first toast which is in the first line!

Comment: so the log still says permission denied and can't access the file at the location /data/ Since you are using API level below 23, Have you mentioned the READ and WRITE permissions in the Manifest. Can you place that code as well. Even I am trying to debug what is the issue.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @kapsym I tried even with these permissions: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` also i added below code (go down page) before my main function to ask permission (the main function is shoro()) but didn't work. but i haven't tried with your permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Answer (score 0):

public void shoro(View v) throws IOException {

```
    Toast.makeText(this,"ok2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    vfile = "Contacts" + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis()+".vcf";
    vCard = new ArrayList<String>();
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor!=null&&cursor.getCount()>0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"ok3",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for(int i =0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
        {

            get(cursor);
            Log.d("TAG", "Contact "+(i+1)+"VcF String is"+vCard.get(i));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("TAG", "No Contacts in Your Phone");
    }

}

public void get(Cursor cursor) throws IOException {
    Toast.makeText(this,"ok4",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
    AssetFileDescriptor fd;

    fd = this.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");

    FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
    fis.read(buf);
    String vcardstring= new String(buf);
    vCard.add(vcardstring);

    String storage_path = Environment.getDataDirectory().toString() + File.separator + vfile;
    FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(storage_path, false);
    mFileOutputStream.write(vcardstring.toString().getBytes());


}
```

First look at those Toasts, i put them to find out until which line the app goes on. weirdly first time that i asked these questions i forgot to add phone number to my contacts (i have 3 contacts for test) and when i ran the app (when i hadn't add number) the app goes on without any error, but didn't work (our previous conversation was about this, my fault :D). then when i checked the Toasts, i find out that app never reach "ok3" Toast. after that when i add number to contacts, now the app cannot run even. when i press the button, it crashes and close.i put the lines from the run in a notepad which is in link below (API 17):

`https://ufile.io/i3gu4`

i tested this on API 24 and 21 also, but same problem. what could be the problem?

Comment: @ Magasvazn I was able to figure out the issue. See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

public void terp(View v) throws IOException {
        Toast.makeText(this,"ok",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

```
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{ Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS }, 12345);
    } else {
        // WE ALREADY HAVE PERMISSION, RUN THE MAIN FUNCTION
        shoro();
    }

}


public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"salam1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if ((requestCode == 12345) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"salam2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // WE GOT THE PERMISSION, RUN THE MAIN FUNCTION
        try {
            shoro();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

shoro() is the main function.

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't allow you to create files in **Environment.getDataDirectoy()**. this points to /data folder which is for system to use. If you want to use internal storage you can use /data/data/your_app_package storage. To get access to this you have to just change 1 line of your code -

```
String storage_path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + vfile;
```

To verify that your file is created, You can do the following steps

1. Open Android Device Monitor from Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor
2. select the simulator in the Devices tab on the left.
3. select File Explorer tab on the right section
4. Go to /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME folder. Inside that you will see the Files section where your file will be created

If you want to use external storage use **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()** method.

To understand the different Paths in Android device, look [here](https://gist.github.com/granoeste/5574148)

UPDATE 1
After Discussion here is the updated code. There were multiple problems - 
1) We need to accept multiple permissions and cater to all of them for API >= 23
2) AssetFileDescriptor gives length as -1 for API > = 24
Hence the code was breaking.

so change at 2 places - Change your get method -

```
 public void get(Cursor cursor) throws IOException {
    Toast.makeText(this,"ok4",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
    Uri vCardUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
    AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor;
    String vcardstring="";
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {

        FileInputStream inputStream=null;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        ByteArrayOutputStream ous = null;
        try {
            assetFileDescriptor = this.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(vCardUri, "r");

            if (assetFileDescriptor != null) {
                ous = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int read = 0;
                inputStream = assetFileDescriptor.createInputStream();
                while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    ous.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Vcard for the contact " + lookupKey + " not found", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Problem creating stream from the assetFileDescriptor.", e);
        }finally {
            try {
                if (ous != null)
                    ous.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            try {
                if (inputStream != null)
                    inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        vcardstring= new String(ous.toByteArray());

    }else{

        assetFileDescriptor = this.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(vCardUri, "r");

        FileInputStream fis = assetFileDescriptor.createInputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[(int) assetFileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength()];
        fis.read(buf);
        vcardstring= new String(buf);

    }


    vCard.add(vcardstring);
    Log.i("File Kapil", "path "+getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath().toString());
    String storage_path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + vfile;
    FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(storage_path, false);
    mFileOutputStream.write(vcardstring.toString().getBytes());

}
```

And for request permission change -

```
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 0:
            boolean isPerpermissionForAllGranted = false;
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && permissions.length==grantResults.length) {
                for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++){
                    if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        isPerpermissionForAllGranted=true;
                    }else{
                        isPerpermissionForAllGranted=false;
                    }
                }

                Log.e("value", "Permission Granted, Now you can use local drive .");
            } else {
                isPerpermissionForAllGranted=true;
                Log.e("value", "Permission Denied, You cannot use local drive .");
            }
            if(isPerpermissionForAllGranted){
                shoro();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

And in your Shoro method change the code a bit-

```
 public void shoro(){
   boolean isPermissionGiven =  isStoragePermissionGranted();
   Toast.makeText(this,"ok2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (isPermissionGiven){
        // Do stuff
    }
 }
```

The complete code can be found - [Here](https://pastebin.com/i0Rfv2E6)

Comment: Thanks man, it seems the problem fixed only on APIs which don't need permissions (older than 22 i think) the app on newer APIs crash again with this error in run section: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=12345, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.k.backup2/com.example.k.backup2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1`

Comment: Also i changed the 4th line of the code below to this: `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{ Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 12345);
` didn't work again. maybe i'm wrong, but idk what to do now. btw, app works fine on other APIs (which don't need permissions) and i could see the .vcf file as you said.

Comment: I am looking at higher API version. give me 15 mins

Comment: @Magasvazn sorry it took me so much time. I have updated the answer with the updated code. Have a Look.

Comment: @Magasvazn So did this finally work for you? It worked for me atleast on both APIs

Comment: My Pleasure. It was a good puzzle for me as well. Please accept the answer :)

Comment: Nice :D i have another question which i posted right now. if you like and have time... you can check it :D i'm really new to Java. it's really hard in compare to VB.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45331886/changing-a-contacts-name-by-selecting-them-change-those-ones-which-selected

Comment: Sure will look into it. Would request you to accept the answer for me to get rewarded the points :)