# Changing a contact's name by selecting them (change those ones which selected)

Tags: android, edit, contacts

I have this code that change all contacts names, but i want to make it to only change those ones which i selected. i mean when i touch the button, a window shows up that let me select which contacts i want to change. i mean multiple contacts, not only one:

```
public void editContacts() throws RemoteException, OperationApplicationException {

    int count=0;
    try {
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {

                    builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)))});
                    name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, "haminDota2");
                    ops.add(builder.build());

                    getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                    count++;
                    if (count==2){
                        break;
                    }

            }

        }

        cur.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: So have you already created the window that allows you to select the contacts?

Comment: No, idk how to do that. i thought it has a little code to open that window!

Comment: So there is no standard available as far as i know. You will have to design a custom contact picker. You can refer to http://sachindotg.blogspot.in/2013/11/android-simple-multi-contacts-picker.html

Its a bit old but the basic crust on how to do it remains the same